# Why my comments and questions are repeatedly getting deleted?

Tags: support, questions, comments, deleted-comments, deleted-questions

Few hours ago I have posted a comment under [this](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/69930/28276) downvoted post saying  that  three high reputation users have answered it and it doesn't deserve to be downvoted.

Surprisingly the    comment got deleted  immediately after some time of posting.

There are [some](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/69927/highest-number-of-public-holidays-in-country-region#comment284165_69927)  such comments currently are  present under other posts also.

In second case few days ago one of [my  questions](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/67865/what-possible-legal-action-a-country-will-face-if-its-proved-that-a-leaked-biol) also was deleted  after closing down. (Unfortunately I don't have saved link of that) , but other closed posts with lots of negative votes are still present without deletion.

I am wondering why my activities are being deleted repetadely even if they are not offensive , abusive or are in any case problematic.

Will the mods here  spare some time to explain why?

Comment: It should be pointed out just because some high rep users answered your question doesn't mean others can't think it is worth downvoting and as of now your question only has 2 downvotes.

Answer (score 10):

Your comment was deleted because we generally discourage comments regarding up/downvotes - see the examples in the [Help Center article on the commenting privilege](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment):

> **When shouldn't I comment?**
>
> Comments are not recommended for any of the following:
>
> - **Compliments** which do not add new information ("+1, great answer!"); instead, upvote it and pay it forward;
> - **Discussion of community behavior or site policies**; please use meta instead.

Your comment, "If a question gets three answers from high reputation users then it certainly do not deserve downvote." seems to me to fit into these categories.

I don't think it's fair to say that your comments are repeatedly deleted - you have only had two comments removed this year, the other being removed as 'no longer needed' after the changes you suggested to a post were made.

If you see comments from other users which you'd like us to take a look at, you can [flag them](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) for our attention.

Regarding your deleted question, ["What possible legal action a country will face if it's proved that a leaked biological material from it caused millions of deaths worldwide?"](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/67865), this question was deleted by three community members after being closed - also by community votes. The close reason was as follows:

> Questions asking for the internal motivations of people, how specific
> individuals would behave in hypothetical situations or predictions for
> future events are off-topic, because answers would be based on
> speculation and their correctness could not be verified with sources
> available to the public.

I don't see a need to overrule the community's decision in this case, but if other members with the [moderator tools privilege](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) disagree, they can cast undelete votes to restore your question.

I appreciate it can be frustrating when your content is deleted without explanation, so hopefully this helps you understand why your content was curated in this instance.

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply. Reading the deleted  question - It actually isn't hypothetical because there are cases of accidental release of pathogens from labs. There is a full article on wikipedia regarding laboratory biosecurity incidents.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_laboratory_biosecurity_incidents

Comment: So such cases happened before and the Q. was just inquiring about is there any possibility of legal action by international organisation s against the nations who do not take proper care in handling deadly pathogens.

Comment: Secondly  I am  completely with you about  not encouraging comments regarding up/downvotes issue.And being member of  stack exchange for about almost 6 years I am quite aware about the site policies. But I commented because I  thought that a lot of questions  here are getting   a single   downvote after some time. And the comment was reaction to that.But it got deleted and other similar comments didn't.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar We moderators can not be expected to read every single comment posted on the site. Your comment came to our attention because it was flagged by another user. When you see any similar comments, please flag them so we can delete them too.

Answer (score 3):

Those comments are generally flagged as "no longer needed" because it has rarely accomplished anything. Presumably, the question is getting downvoted because some people think it is too simple for this site or shows a lack of research effort (though, I can't read minds, so I may be wrong).

As for why your question needs to be deleted when it's not trolling/rude/spam/abusive is because of [the broken window theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broken_windows_theory), and it was off topic because it was asking for motivations.

Disclaimer: I'm not a mod, but I do have access to moderator tools, idk if that counts.